# Implementing c binary division in o(1)

Tags: c, binary, division

I found this (slightly modified) code to implement division on unsigned numbers:

```
#include <climits>
#include <stdio.h>



unsigned divide(unsigned dividend, unsigned divisor) { 


    unsigned current = 1;
    unsigned answer=0;

    if ( divisor > dividend) 
        return 0;

    if ( divisor == dividend)
        return 1;

    while (divisor <= dividend) {   // this will not work with UINT_MAX
        divisor <<= 1;
        current <<= 1;
    }

    divisor >>= 1;
    current >>= 1;

    while (current!=0) {
        if ( dividend >= divisor) {
            dividend -= divisor;
            answer |= current;
        }
        current >>= 1;
        divisor >>= 1;
    }    
    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int x =0;
    x = divide (UINT_MAX,113);
    printf ("%u",x);

    return 0;
}
```

It works great with "normal" values, but dividing the max unsigned int value creates a problem; since it's Oxffffffff it is not possible to shift *divisor* enough to make it bigger - any further shifting will push the divisor over the 32 bit limit and destroy the value creating an infinite loop. Can I get a suggestion on how to fix this error? perhaps even create a hard code case?

Comment: I'm don't know how to hard code this special case, as the other number would still be a variable. This is still O(1) as the loop would not execute more than 32 times.

Comment: Technically it loops the number of bits in the number.  Big-O is a theoretical construct, so _normally_ you use theoretical numbers.  So your code would _normally_ be called `O(log(n))`.  If you start taking "limited ranged numbers" into consideration then almost all algorithms are O(1), which is a pointless metric.

Comment: If you find this interesting I would suggest the amazing book [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
while (divisor <= dividend) {   // this will not work with UINT_MAX
    divisor <<= 1;
    current <<= 1;
}

divisor >>= 1;
current >>= 1;
```

try

```
unsigned k = 1 << (sizeof(unsigned) * 8 - 1);
while (((divisor & k) == 0) && ((divisor << 1) <= dividend)) {
    divisor <<= 1;
    current <<= 1;
}
```

The idea is that in the suggested algorithm the last left shift of `divisor` and `current` are compensated by a right shift later. So we may avoid it at the first place.

Comment: Thanks! includes the solution to the special case

Comment: @abd Slightly updated to use `1 << sizeof ...` instead of a hardcoded `0x80000000`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be to use unsigned longs.